# Using a for loop to calculate the average

Tags: python

Hi I'm sort of new to programming and I would really appreciate some help with this problem.

I have a list of scores and I would like to create a function which divides each individual score by the calculated average of the whole list. The function should accept a list of scores as an argument and return a list with the modified scores. 
Also, it should make use of a for loop and a return statement.
Here is a brief example of the list of scores I have:
13
22
33
42
25
(there are over 500 scores)

Comment: What code do u have until now?

Comment: If you're that new to programming, you need to investigate a Python tutorial and/or text book first. There are several tutorials online, found with Google.

Comment: This looks like a homework problem. What part of the problem are you stuck on? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tbh, the wording of your question was a little confusing, but here's what you would do.

```
def scoreAvg(scores):
  scoresSum = sum(scores) 
  scoresSum /= len(scores)
  newScores = [] 
  for i in scores:
    i /= scoresSum 
    newScores.append(i)
  return newScores

print(scoreAvg([13,22,33,42,25]))
```

You said you were pretty new to python, so I'll give you a rundown of what's happening here. Input 'scores' is a list containing our set of example scores (remember to enclose the input in square brackets). We find the sum of that list with `sum()` and the length with `len()`. We then begin a for loop to loop through the elements of scores, and divide each element by the avg, then append that value to a list we created earlier to hold the new scores. Now all we have to do is return that list with `return newScores` !

Hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code.

```
from __future__ import division #For decimal division.

''' Function (func) '''
def func(lst):
    new_list = [] #Define an empty new list.
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        new_list += [ lst[i]*len(lst) / sum(lst) ]  

    return new_list    

mylist = [13, 22, 33, 42, 25] #List you wish to enter.
mod_list = func(lst = mylist) #Modified list.

print mod_list #Prints output (mod_list).
>>>[0.48148148148148145, 0.8148148148148148, 1.2222222222222223, 1.5555555555555556, 0.9259259259259259]
```

In the above code, each element of `new_list` is element of input list `(lst=mylist)` divided by average of input list. One can obtain average by using the following: `average = sum of input list / number of elements in input list`. In python, the function `len()` gives you the number of items of an object (e.g. list). The function `sum()` gives you the sum elements of an object.

I hope this was helpful. Let me know if you have any questions. =)